# Silex + FOQElasticaBundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, silex

My goal is to link the FOQElasticBundle with my Silex website.
The problem is that the documentationn of FOQElasticBundle states that I only have to put some basic stuff in my config.yml file.

See: https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle#declare-a-client

So far I can't find a config.yml file anywhere and I don't know if I have to create it and if so where to put it. 
Did I made the wrong choice making my website with Silex instead of Symfony itself? 
Or is it possible to load the FOQElasticBundle?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use Symfony Bundles in Silex directly.
Silex integrates third party libraries via Service Providers, which act like some sort of adapters for third party libs.

If you want the convenience of bundles i suggest you better use Symfony.

Otherwise you could try to [write a Service Provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers.html#creating-a-provider) for the Elastica library yourself
or integrate it directly as its done here:
https://github.com/4devs/demo-silex/blob/master/web/index.php

```
$app['elastica.host'] = "localhost";
$app['elastica.port'] = 9200;

$app['elastica'] = function ($app) {
    return new \Elastica\Client(array(
        'host' => $app['elastica.host'],
        'port' => $app['elastica.port']
    ));
};
```

Unfortunatly there is no Elastica Service Provider listed here:
https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/wiki/Third-Party-ServiceProviders